# AttachTo dosen't seem to work. Object is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I use entity Framework 4.

```
 var entity = rep.GetEntityTxt<AreaTypeText>(PKey, LangID);

 _db.AttachTo("AreaTypeText",entity);
 entity.Txt = "TEST";
 _db.SaveChanges();
```

When I check in debug mode on the _db variable, my AreaTypeText object is null. Nothing seem to be attached.

**UPDATE WORKING EXAMPLE**

I need to detach to be able to change the EntityState to Modified before SaveChange.

```
var pluralizer = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
            TEntity entity = _db.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id && p.LangID == langid);

            if (entity != null)
            {
                _db.Detach(entity);
                entity.Txt = value;
                _db.AddObject(pluralizer.Pluralize(entity.GetType().Name), entity);
                _db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
                _db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: can't you do `_db.AreaTypeText.Attach(entity)`? or `_db.AttachTo("AreaTypeTexts", entity)` (note pluralization on entity set name). plus your code doesn't make sense. why are you retrieving an entity then attempting to attach it? it already is.

Comment: You need to show the code which *doesn't* work, not just the part which does.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I Need to detach the entity from context to be able to set the State to Modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pluralizer = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
            TEntity entity = _db.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id && p.LangID == langid);

            if (entity != null)
            {
                _db.Detach(entity);
                entity.Txt = value;
                _db.AddObject(pluralizer.Pluralize(entity.GetType().Name), entity);
                _db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
                _db.SaveChanges();
```